# Reset event called without calling reset

Tags: backbone.js

Mysteriously, the `reset` event of `myCollection` is being called, although I don't seem to be triggering it anywhere.

Looking at the [backbone source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html), the `reset` event can be triggered either when calling `myCollection.reset` or `myCollection.sort`, but I'm doing neither!

It's quite frustrating because I cannot tell which function triggered the event, just that it has been triggered. Any clues? How can I debug this?

Comment: You can add a breakpoint, at the reset method in backbone, in firebug and check the `Stack` tab.

Comment: Maybe it's pretty obvious but, are you aware that the 'reset' event is triggered when you fetch the collection from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The collection `reset` event will also be called when `collection.fetch` is used and any new data is returned.

See [backbone.js documentation on this](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch) for more information.